# Graphical User Interface

Tags: gui, c++, gtk3, wayland

I am doing development in C++. I heard that GTK is being replaced by Wayland.

Which GUI libraries are suitable for C++ for long-term?

Comment: Did you check package of QT-Designer ?! There is QT 5 in the meantime.
Here is a link: https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

Wayland is a replacement for [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). GTK+ is still the GUI toolkit used by GNOME and some other desktop environments and there are no plans to replace it.

The two big GUI libraries for Linux are [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) and [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/). Both can be used with C++ and are likely to stay for the foreseeable future.

Which one is better for you depends on which desktop environment is your primary target. Both libraries can be used with any desktop environment but your app will have a different look and feel if it's using the "wrong" GUI toolkit for your desktop environment.

If you want your app to be used on other systems than Linux Qt is usually the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

#### Glade

Although you can use C++ code to instantiate and arrange widgets, this can soon become tedious and repetitive. And it requires a recompilation to show changes. The Glade application allows you to layout widgets on screen and then save an XML description of the arrangement.

This has the following advantages:

- Less C++ code is required.
- UI changes can be seen more quickly, so UIs are able to improve.
- Designers without programming skills can create and edit UIs.

The user interfaces designed in Glade are stored in the well-known XML format, enabling easy integration with external tools. You will probably want to use it with tools such as libglade, which can load the XML files and create the interfaces at runtime.

To install Glade GTK+ User Interface Builder in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install glade
```

To install only the development files for the GTK+ library without installing Glade type:

```
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
```

---

#### Qt Creator

Qt Creator is a cross-platform integrated development environment (IDE)  designed to make development with the Qt application framework faster and easier.

It includes:

- An advanced C++ code editor
- Integrated GUI layout and forms designer
- Project and build management tools
- Integrated, context-sensitive help system
- Visual debugger
- Rapid code navigation tools
- Supports multiple platforms
- Qt Quick Designer

To install QT Creator in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install qtcreator
```

```
$ apt-cache depends qtcreator | grep qt  
qtcreator  
  Depends: libqt5sql5-sqlite  
  Depends: qml-module-qtqml-models2  
  Depends: qml-module-qtquick-controls  
  Depends: qml-module-qtquick2  
  Depends: qtchooser  
    qtchooser:i386  
  Depends: qtcreator-data  
  Depends: libqbsqtprofilesetup1.10  
  Depends: libqt5concurrent5  
  Depends: libqt5core5a   
  Depends: libqt5designer5  
  Depends: libqt5designercomponents5  
  Depends: libqt5gui5  
  Depends: libqt5help5  
  Depends: libqt5network5  
  Depends: libqt5printsupport5  
  Depends: libqt5qml5  
  Depends: libqt5quick5  
  Depends: libqt5quickwidgets5  
  Depends: libqt5sql5  
  Depends: libqt5widgets5  
  Depends: libqt5xml5  
  Depends: <qtdeclarative-abi-5-9-5>  
    libqt5qml5  
  Recommends: qt5-doc  
  Recommends: qt5-qmltooling-plugins  
  Recommends: qtbase5-dev-tools  
    qtbase5-dev-tools:i386  
  Recommends: qtcreator-doc  
  Recommends: qtdeclarative5-dev-tools  
    qtdeclarative5-dev-tools:i386  
  Recommends: qttools5-dev-tools  
    qttools5-dev-tools:i386  
  Recommends: qttranslations5-l10n  
  Recommends: qtxmlpatterns5-dev-tools  
    qtxmlpatterns5-dev-tools:i386  
    qterminal
```

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>